# Pressure inside a cell

Tags: cell-biology, biophysics, cytoskeleton

In this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3925878/), in the introduction 3 paragraph first line they said:

> The flow of water plays a critical part in these processes. Recent
> experiments suggest the pressure equilibrates within cells giving rise
> to intercellular flows of cytosol that cells may exploit to create
> lamellipodial protrusions or blebs of locomotion

Equilibration of pressure inside cell is something I don't understand. Okay, in the lamellipodium part of the cell, the cytosol were pushed to that place. It means that there is a pressure gradient so the pressure in the lamellipodium should be different in the pressure of the bulk of the cell where the nucleus is present. Some model assumes that they are equal like [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncb1965).

Can any body explain what do we mean exactly by pressure equilibrates and volume conservation inside cell? Why it needs to be conserved knowing that the cell is changing its shape i.e. its area and thus the volume? Any good citations?

Comment: Seems like you'd find a lot in the papers this one cites, such as 9, 8, and 17.